Streamlit and GPT-4 Turbo with Vision
I am trying to write a streamlit app that takes a prompt, takes a photo, and then run a GPT-4 Vision analysis on the photo. The app does not run beyond line ~13 (the screen just stops after the photo is taken, with no traceback). Would anyone know what the issue might be?

import streamlit as st


import base64
import requests

# OpenAI API Key
api_key = "xxx"

title = st.text_input("Your prompt:","What is in the picture?")


img_file_buffer  = st.camera_input("Take a picture")
    
if img_file_buffer is not None:
    
    # To read image file buffer as bytes:
    bytes_data = img_file_buffer .getvalue()
    
    # Convert bytes data to base64
    base64_encoded = base64.b64encode(bytes_data).decode()

    headers = {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "Authorization": f"Bearer {api_key}"
    }

    payload = {
      "model": "gpt-4-turbo",
      "messages": [
        {
          "role": "user",
          "content": [
            {
              "type": "text",
              "text": title
            },
            {
              "type": "image_url",
              "image_url": {
                "url": f"data:image/jpeg;base64,{base64_encoded}"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "max_tokens": 300
    }

    response = requests.post("https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions", headers=headers, json=payload)

    print(response.json())

    st.text(response.json())


which line is 13?

Maybe first use print() (and print(type(...)), print(len(...)), etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called "print debugging" and it helps to see what code is really doing.

i've tested it on a few machines, the problem is not a coding problem, it is some weird compatibility issue with my laptop and the recent streamlit issues. I've had to downgrade my streamlit to 1.24.0 or earlier, to make it work.
